# how to return to original layout of div if clicked anywhere in the body or outside div

Tags: jquery

I created a facebook like "what's on your mind" box that when you click on the field an additional div and buttons will appear. How would I make it so that when I click outside of that area the entire box will go back to normal.

[Here's the link to the page I created](http://randomreflect.com/status)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('body').on('click', function(e) {

  if(e.target.id != 'textarea-container') {
    $('#show-button1, #show-button2').hide();
    $('#textarea-container').removeClass('style2');
  }

});
```

Comment: i tried putting the code between <script></script> it's not working.

Comment: @randolph.romero make a fiddle

Comment: @randolph.romero this code written in jQuery, but you site don't have jQuery included and that is the problem I think

Comment: I added a script <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script> still not working.

Comment: @randolph.romero the code I written is eligible for jquery 1.7.+

Answer (score 0):

Update - Add `onclick` to your `body`:

```
<body onclick="hideDiv(event);">
```

JS:

```
function hideDiv(e){
      e = e || window.event;
      var element = e.target || e.srcElement;
      if(element.id != "textarea-container" && element.id != "show-button1" &&
         element.id != "divDate" && element.id != "show-button2"){

        var textareaContainer = document.getElementById("textarea-container");
        var txtArea = textareaContainer.getElementsByTagName("TEXTAREA")[0];
        txtArea.className = "style1";
        document.getElementById("show-button1").style.display = 'none'; // hide button
        document.getElementById("show-button2").style.display = 'none'; // hide button
      }
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the quick reply, but when I click on the icons/send button it closes the entire div immediately.

Comment: Is he notified now? @randolph.romero (I always forget too)

Comment: tried that solution this is what happens [link](http://randomreflect.com/status_bycoder)